# Boost::log и CMake, Could NOT find Boost (missing: log)

Tags: c++, cmake, boost

При попытке сбилдить CMake проект, используя Visual Code, я получаю такую ошибку:

```
[proc] Выполнение команды: "C://Program Files (x86)//CMake//bin//cmake.exe" --no-warn-unused-cli "-DBOOST_ROOT:STRING=C:\Program Files\boost\boost_1_74_0" "-DBOOST_INCLUDEDIR:STRING=C:\Program Files\boost\boost_1_74_0\include" "-DBOOST_LIBRARYDIR:STRING=C:\Program Files\boost\boost_1_74_0\stage\lib" -DCMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS:BOOL=TRUE -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE:STRING=Debug "-DCMAKE_C_COMPILER:FILEPATH=C:\Program Files\mingw-w64\x86_64-8.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v6-rev0\mingw64\bin\gcc.exe" "-DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER:FILEPATH=C:\Program Files\mingw-w64\x86_64-8.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v6-rev0\mingw64\bin\g++.exe" -Hf:/proj -Bf:/proj/build -G "MinGW Makefiles"
[cmake] Not searching for unused variables given on the command line.
[cmake] -- [ C:/Program Files (x86)/CMake/share/cmake-3.18/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1491 ] _boost_TEST_VERSIONS = <unset>
[cmake] -- [ C:/Program Files (x86)/CMake/share/cmake-3.18/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1492 ] Boost_USE_MULTITHREADED = "TRUE"
[cmake] -- [ C:/Program Files (x86)/CMake/share/cmake-3.18/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1493 ] Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS = "ON"
[cmake] -- [ C:/Program Files (x86)/CMake/share/cmake-3.18/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1494 ] Boost_USE_STATIC_RUNTIME = <unset>
[cmake] -- [ C:/Program Files (x86)/CMake/share/cmake-3.18/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1495 ] Boost_ADDITIONAL_VERSIONS = <unset>
[cmake] -- [ C:/Program Files (x86)/CMake/share/cmake-3.18/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1496 ] Boost_NO_SYSTEM_PATHS = <unset>
[cmake] -- [ C:/Program Files (x86)/CMake/share/cmake-3.18/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1528 ] BOOST_ROOT = "C:\Program Files\boost\boost_1_74_0"
[cmake] -- [ C:/Program Files (x86)/CMake/share/cmake-3.18/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1529 ] ENV{BOOST_ROOT} = "C:\Program Files\boost\boost_1_74_0"
[cmake] -- [ C:/Program Files (x86)/CMake/share/cmake-3.18/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1530 ] BOOST_INCLUDEDIR = "C:\Program Files\boost\boost_1_74_0\include"
[cmake] -- [ C:/Program Files (x86)/CMake/share/cmake-3.18/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1531 ] ENV{BOOST_INCLUDEDIR} = "C:\Program Files\boost\boost_1_74_0\include"
[cmake] -- [ C:/Program Files (x86)/CMake/share/cmake-3.18/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1532 ] BOOST_LIBRARYDIR = "C:\Program Files\boost\boost_1_74_0\stage\lib"
[cmake] -- [ C:/Program Files (x86)/CMake/share/cmake-3.18/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1533 ] ENV{BOOST_LIBRARYDIR} = "C:\Program Files\boost\boost_1_74_0\stage\lib"
[cmake] -- [ C:/Program Files (x86)/CMake/share/cmake-3.18/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1621 ] location of version.hpp: C:/Program Files/boost/boost_1_74_0/boost/version.hpp
[cmake] -- [ C:/Program Files (x86)/CMake/share/cmake-3.18/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1661 ] Boost_VERSION = "1.74.0"
[cmake] -- [ C:/Program Files (x86)/CMake/share/cmake-3.18/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1662 ] Boost_VERSION_STRING = "1.74.0"
[cmake] -- [ C:/Program Files (x86)/CMake/share/cmake-3.18/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1663 ] Boost_VERSION_MACRO = "107400"
[cmake] -- [ C:/Program Files (x86)/CMake/share/cmake-3.18/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1664 ] Boost_VERSION_MAJOR = "1"
[cmake] -- [ C:/Program Files (x86)/CMake/share/cmake-3.18/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1665 ] Boost_VERSION_MINOR = "74"
[cmake] -- [ C:/Program Files (x86)/CMake/share/cmake-3.18/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1666 ] Boost_VERSION_PATCH = "0"
[cmake] -- [ C:/Program Files (x86)/CMake/share/cmake-3.18/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1667 ] Boost_VERSION_COUNT = "3"
[cmake] -- [ C:/Program Files (x86)/CMake/share/cmake-3.18/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1691 ] Boost_LIB_PREFIX = "lib"
[cmake] -- [ C:/Program Files (x86)/CMake/share/cmake-3.18/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1692 ] Boost_NAMESPACE = "boost"
[cmake] -- [ C:/Program Files (x86)/CMake/share/cmake-3.18/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:801 ] _boost_COMPILER = "-mgw8" (guessed)
[cmake] -- [ C:/Program Files (x86)/CMake/share/cmake-3.18/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1728 ] _boost_MULTITHREADED = "-mt"
[cmake] -- [ C:/Program Files (x86)/CMake/share/cmake-3.18/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1805 ] _boost_ARCHITECTURE_TAG = "" (detected)
[cmake] -- [ C:/Program Files (x86)/CMake/share/cmake-3.18/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1809 ] _boost_RELEASE_ABI_TAG = "-"
[cmake] -- [ C:/Program Files (x86)/CMake/share/cmake-3.18/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1810 ] _boost_DEBUG_ABI_TAG = "-d"
[cmake] -- [ C:/Program Files (x86)/CMake/share/cmake-3.18/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1870 ] _boost_LIBRARY_SEARCH_DIRS_RELEASE = "C:\Program Files\boost\boost_1_74_0\stage\lib;C:\Program Files\boost\boost_1_74_0/lib;C:\Program Files\boost\boost_1_74_0/stage/lib;C:/Program Files/boost/boost_1_74_0/lib;C:/Program Files/boost/boost_1_74_0/../lib;C:/Program Files/boost/boost_1_74_0/stage/lib;PATHS;C:/boost/lib;C:/boost;/sw/local/lib"
[cmake] -- [ C:/Program Files (x86)/CMake/share/cmake-3.18/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1871 ] _boost_LIBRARY_SEARCH_DIRS_DEBUG = "C:\Program Files\boost\boost_1_74_0\stage\lib;C:\Program Files\boost\boost_1_74_0/lib;C:\Program Files\boost\boost_1_74_0/stage/lib;C:/Program Files/boost/boost_1_74_0/lib;C:/Program Files/boost/boost_1_74_0/../lib;C:/Program Files/boost/boost_1_74_0/stage/lib;PATHS;C:/boost/lib;C:/boost;/sw/local/lib"
[cmake] CMake Warning at C:/Program Files (x86)/CMake/share/cmake-3.18/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1187 (message):
[cmake]   New Boost version may have incorrect or missing dependencies and imported
[cmake]   targets
[cmake] Call Stack (most recent call first):
[cmake]   C:/Program Files (x86)/CMake/share/cmake-3.18/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1311 (_Boost_COMPONENT_DEPENDENCIES)
[cmake]   C:/Program Files (x86)/CMake/share/cmake-3.18/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1919 (_Boost_MISSING_DEPENDENCIES)
[cmake]   CMakeLists.txt:30 (find_package)
[cmake] 
[cmake] 
[cmake] CMake Warning at C:/Program Files (x86)/CMake/share/cmake-3.18/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1187 (message):
[cmake]   New Boost version may have incorrect or missing dependencies and imported
[cmake]   targets
[cmake] Call Stack (most recent call first):
[cmake]   C:/Program Files (x86)/CMake/share/cmake-3.18/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1311 (_Boost_COMPONENT_DEPENDENCIES)
[cmake]   C:/Program Files (x86)/CMake/share/cmake-3.18/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1919 (_Boost_MISSING_DEPENDENCIES)
[cmake]   CMakeLists.txt:30 (find_package)
[cmake] 
[cmake] 
[cmake] CMake Warning at C:/Program Files (x86)/CMake/share/cmake-3.18/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1187 (message):
[cmake]   New Boost version may have incorrect or missing dependencies and imported
[cmake]   targets
[cmake] Call Stack (most recent call first):
[cmake]   C:/Program Files (x86)/CMake/share/cmake-3.18/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1311 (_Boost_COMPONENT_DEPENDENCIES)
[cmake]   C:/Program Files (x86)/CMake/share/cmake-3.18/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1919 (_Boost_MISSING_DEPENDENCIES)
[cmake]   CMakeLists.txt:30 (find_package)
[cmake] 
[cmake] 
[cmake] CMake Warning at C:/Program Files (x86)/CMake/share/cmake-3.18/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1187 (message):
[cmake]   New Boost version may have incorrect or missing dependencies and imported
[cmake]   targets
[cmake] Call Stack (most recent call first):
[cmake]   C:/Program Files (x86)/CMake/share/cmake-3.18/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1311 (_Boost_COMPONENT_DEPENDENCIES)
[cmake]   C:/Program Files (x86)/CMake/share/cmake-3.18/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1919 (_Boost_MISSING_DEPENDENCIES)
[cmake]   CMakeLists.txt:30 (find_package)
[cmake] 
[cmake] 
[cmake] CMake Warning at C:/Program Files (x86)/CMake/share/cmake-3.18/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1187 (message):
[cmake]   New Boost version may have incorrect or missing dependencies and imported
[cmake]   targets
[cmake] Call Stack (most recent call first):
[cmake]   C:/Program Files (x86)/CMake/share/cmake-3.18/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1311 (_Boost_COMPONENT_DEPENDENCIES)
[cmake]   C:/Program Files (x86)/CMake/share/cmake-3.18/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1919 (_Boost_MISSING_DEPENDENCIES)
[cmake]   CMakeLists.txt:30 (find_package)
[cmake] 
[cmake] 
[cmake] CMake Warning at C:/Program Files (x86)/CMake/share/cmake-3.18/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1187 (message):
[cmake]   New Boost version may have incorrect or missing dependencies and imported
[cmake]   targets
[cmake] Call Stack (most recent call first):
[cmake]   C:/Program Files (x86)/CMake/share/cmake-3.18/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1311 (_Boost_COMPONENT_DEPENDENCIES)
[cmake]   C:/Program Files (x86)/CMake/share/cmake-3.18/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1919 (_Boost_MISSING_DEPENDENCIES)
[cmake]   CMakeLists.txt:30 (find_package)
[cmake] 
[cmake] 
[cmake] CMake Warning at C:/Program Files (x86)/CMake/share/cmake-3.18/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1187 (message):
[cmake]   New Boost version may have incorrect or missing dependencies and imported
[cmake]   targets
[cmake] Call Stack (most recent call first):
[cmake]   C:/Program Files (x86)/CMake/share/cmake-3.18/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1311 (_Boost_COMPONENT_DEPENDENCIES)
[cmake]   C:/Program Files (x86)/CMake/share/cmake-3.18/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1919 (_Boost_MISSING_DEPENDENCIES)
[cmake]   CMakeLists.txt:30 (find_package)
[cmake] 
[cmake] 
[cmake] CMake Warning at C:/Program Files (x86)/CMake/share/cmake-3.18/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1187 (message):
[cmake]   New Boost version may have incorrect or missing dependencies and imported
[cmake]   targets
[cmake] Call Stack (most recent call first):
[cmake]   C:/Program Files (x86)/CMake/share/cmake-3.18/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1311 (_Boost_COMPONENT_DEPENDENCIES)
[cmake]   C:/Program Files (x86)/CMake/share/cmake-3.18/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1919 (_Boost_MISSING_DEPENDENCIES)
[cmake]   CMakeLists.txt:30 (find_package)
[cmake] 
[cmake] 
[cmake] -- [ C:/Program Files (x86)/CMake/share/cmake-3.18/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:2056 ] Searching for LOG_LIBRARY_RELEASE: libboost_log-mgw8-mt-1_74;libboost_log-mgw8-mt;libboost_log-mgw8-mt;libboost_log-mt-1_74;libboost_log-mt;libboost_log-mt;libboost_log-mt;libboost_log;libboost_log-mgw8-mt-s-1_74;libboost_log-mgw8-mt-s;libboost_log-mgw8-mt-s;libboost_log-mt-s-1_74;libboost_log-mt-s;libboost_log-mt-s
[cmake] -- [ C:/Program Files (x86)/CMake/share/cmake-3.18/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:2111 ] Searching for LOG_LIBRARY_DEBUG: libboost_log-mgw8-mt-d-1_74;libboost_log-mgw8-mt-d;libboost_log-mgw8-mt-d;libboost_log-mt-d-1_74;libboost_log-mt-d;libboost_log-mt-d;libboost_log-mt;libboost_log;libboost_log-mgw8-mt-s-d-1_74;libboost_log-mgw8-mt-s-d;libboost_log-mgw8-mt-s-d;libboost_log-mt-s-d-1_74;libboost_log-mt-s-d;libboost_log-mt-s-d
[cmake] -- [ C:/Program Files (x86)/CMake/share/cmake-3.18/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:2056 ] Searching for DATE_TIME_LIBRARY_RELEASE: libboost_date_time-mgw8-mt-1_74;libboost_date_time-mgw8-mt;libboost_date_time-mgw8-mt;libboost_date_time-mt-1_74;libboost_date_time-mt;libboost_date_time-mt;libboost_date_time-mt;libboost_date_time;libboost_date_time-mgw8-mt-s-1_74;libboost_date_time-mgw8-mt-s;libboost_date_time-mgw8-mt-s;libboost_date_time-mt-s-1_74;libboost_date_time-mt-s;libboost_date_time-mt-s
[cmake] -- [ C:/Program Files (x86)/CMake/share/cmake-3.18/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:2111 ] Searching for DATE_TIME_LIBRARY_DEBUG: libboost_date_time-mgw8-mt-d-1_74;libboost_date_time-mgw8-mt-d;libboost_date_time-mgw8-mt-d;libboost_date_time-mt-d-1_74;libboost_date_time-mt-d;libboost_date_time-mt-d;libboost_date_time-mt;libboost_date_time;libboost_date_time-mgw8-mt-s-d-1_74;libboost_date_time-mgw8-mt-s-d;libboost_date_time-mgw8-mt-s-d;libboost_date_time-mt-s-d-1_74;libboost_date_time-mt-s-d;libboost_date_time-mt-s-d
[cmake] -- [ C:/Program Files (x86)/CMake/share/cmake-3.18/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:2056 ] Searching for LOG_SETUP_LIBRARY_RELEASE: libboost_log_setup-mgw8-mt-1_74;libboost_log_setup-mgw8-mt;libboost_log_setup-mgw8-mt;libboost_log_setup-mt-1_74;libboost_log_setup-mt;libboost_log_setup-mt;libboost_log_setup-mt;libboost_log_setup;libboost_log_setup-mgw8-mt-s-1_74;libboost_log_setup-mgw8-mt-s;libboost_log_setup-mgw8-mt-s;libboost_log_setup-mt-s-1_74;libboost_log_setup-mt-s;libboost_log_setup-mt-s
[cmake] -- [ C:/Program Files (x86)/CMake/share/cmake-3.18/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:2111 ] Searching for LOG_SETUP_LIBRARY_DEBUG: libboost_log_setup-mgw8-mt-d-1_74;libboost_log_setup-mgw8-mt-d;libboost_log_setup-mgw8-mt-d;libboost_log_setup-mt-d-1_74;libboost_log_setup-mt-d;libboost_log_setup-mt-d;libboost_log_setup-mt;libboost_log_setup;libboost_log_setup-mgw8-mt-s-d-1_74;libboost_log_setup-mgw8-mt-s-d;libboost_log_setup-mgw8-mt-s-d;libboost_log_setup-mt-s-d-1_74;libboost_log_setup-mt-s-d;libboost_log_setup-mt-s-d
[cmake] -- [ C:/Program Files (x86)/CMake/share/cmake-3.18/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:2056 ] Searching for FILESYSTEM_LIBRARY_RELEASE: libboost_filesystem-mgw8-mt-1_74;libboost_filesystem-mgw8-mt;libboost_filesystem-mgw8-mt;libboost_filesystem-mt-1_74;libboost_filesystem-mt;libboost_filesystem-mt;libboost_filesystem-mt;libboost_filesystem;libboost_filesystem-mgw8-mt-s-1_74;libboost_filesystem-mgw8-mt-s;libboost_filesystem-mgw8-mt-s;libboost_filesystem-mt-s-1_74;libboost_filesystem-mt-s;libboost_filesystem-mt-s
[cmake] -- [ C:/Program Files (x86)/CMake/share/cmake-3.18/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:2111 ] Searching for FILESYSTEM_LIBRARY_DEBUG: libboost_filesystem-mgw8-mt-d-1_74;libboost_filesystem-mgw8-mt-d;libboost_filesystem-mgw8-mt-d;libboost_filesystem-mt-d-1_74;libboost_filesystem-mt-d;libboost_filesystem-mt-d;libboost_filesystem-mt;libboost_filesystem;libboost_filesystem-mgw8-mt-s-d-1_74;libboost_filesystem-mgw8-mt-s-d;libboost_filesystem-mgw8-mt-s-d;libboost_filesystem-mt-s-d-1_74;libboost_filesystem-mt-s-d;libboost_filesystem-mt-s-d
[cmake] -- [ C:/Program Files (x86)/CMake/share/cmake-3.18/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:2056 ] Searching for THREAD_LIBRARY_RELEASE: libboost_thread-mgw8-mt-1_74;libboost_thread-mgw8-mt;libboost_thread-mgw8-mt;libboost_thread-mt-1_74;libboost_thread-mt;libboost_thread-mt;libboost_thread-mt;libboost_thread;libboost_thread-mgw8-mt-s-1_74;libboost_thread-mgw8-mt-s;libboost_thread-mgw8-mt-s;libboost_thread-mt-s-1_74;libboost_thread-mt-s;libboost_thread-mt-s
[cmake] -- [ C:/Program Files (x86)/CMake/share/cmake-3.18/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:2111 ] Searching for THREAD_LIBRARY_DEBUG: libboost_thread-mgw8-mt-d-1_74;libboost_thread-mgw8-mt-d;libboost_thread-mgw8-mt-d;libboost_thread-mt-d-1_74;libboost_thread-mt-d;libboost_thread-mt-d;libboost_thread-mt;libboost_thread;libboost_thread-mgw8-mt-s-d-1_74;libboost_thread-mgw8-mt-s-d;libboost_thread-mgw8-mt-s-d;libboost_thread-mt-s-d-1_74;libboost_thread-mt-s-d;libboost_thread-mt-s-d
[cmake] -- [ C:/Program Files (x86)/CMake/share/cmake-3.18/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:2056 ] Searching for REGEX_LIBRARY_RELEASE: libboost_regex-mgw8-mt-1_74;libboost_regex-mgw8-mt;libboost_regex-mgw8-mt;libboost_regex-mt-1_74;libboost_regex-mt;libboost_regex-mt;libboost_regex-mt;libboost_regex;libboost_regex-mgw8-mt-s-1_74;libboost_regex-mgw8-mt-s;libboost_regex-mgw8-mt-s;libboost_regex-mt-s-1_74;libboost_regex-mt-s;libboost_regex-mt-s
[cmake] -- [ C:/Program Files (x86)/CMake/share/cmake-3.18/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:2111 ] Searching for REGEX_LIBRARY_DEBUG: libboost_regex-mgw8-mt-d-1_74;libboost_regex-mgw8-mt-d;libboost_regex-mgw8-mt-d;libboost_regex-mt-d-1_74;libboost_regex-mt-d;libboost_regex-mt-d;libboost_regex-mt;libboost_regex;libboost_regex-mgw8-mt-s-d-1_74;libboost_regex-mgw8-mt-s-d;libboost_regex-mgw8-mt-s-d;libboost_regex-mt-s-d-1_74;libboost_regex-mt-s-d;libboost_regex-mt-s-d
[cmake] -- [ C:/Program Files (x86)/CMake/share/cmake-3.18/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:2056 ] Searching for CHRONO_LIBRARY_RELEASE: libboost_chrono-mgw8-mt-1_74;libboost_chrono-mgw8-mt;libboost_chrono-mgw8-mt;libboost_chrono-mt-1_74;libboost_chrono-mt;libboost_chrono-mt;libboost_chrono-mt;libboost_chrono;libboost_chrono-mgw8-mt-s-1_74;libboost_chrono-mgw8-mt-s;libboost_chrono-mgw8-mt-s;libboost_chrono-mt-s-1_74;libboost_chrono-mt-s;libboost_chrono-mt-s
[cmake] -- [ C:/Program Files (x86)/CMake/share/cmake-3.18/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:2111 ] Searching for CHRONO_LIBRARY_DEBUG: libboost_chrono-mgw8-mt-d-1_74;libboost_chrono-mgw8-mt-d;libboost_chrono-mgw8-mt-d;libboost_chrono-mt-d-1_74;libboost_chrono-mt-d;libboost_chrono-mt-d;libboost_chrono-mt;libboost_chrono;libboost_chrono-mgw8-mt-s-d-1_74;libboost_chrono-mgw8-mt-s-d;libboost_chrono-mgw8-mt-s-d;libboost_chrono-mt-s-d-1_74;libboost_chrono-mt-s-d;libboost_chrono-mt-s-d
[cmake] -- [ C:/Program Files (x86)/CMake/share/cmake-3.18/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:2056 ] Searching for ATOMIC_LIBRARY_RELEASE: libboost_atomic-mgw8-mt-1_74;libboost_atomic-mgw8-mt;libboost_atomic-mgw8-mt;libboost_atomic-mt-1_74;libboost_atomic-mt;libboost_atomic-mt;libboost_atomic-mt;libboost_atomic;libboost_atomic-mgw8-mt-s-1_74;libboost_atomic-mgw8-mt-s;libboost_atomic-mgw8-mt-s;libboost_atomic-mt-s-1_74;libboost_atomic-mt-s;libboost_atomic-mt-s
[cmake] -- [ C:/Program Files (x86)/CMake/share/cmake-3.18/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:2111 ] Searching for ATOMIC_LIBRARY_DEBUG: libboost_atomic-mgw8-mt-d-1_74;libboost_atomic-mgw8-mt-d;libboost_atomic-mgw8-mt-d;libboost_atomic-mt-d-1_74;libboost_atomic-mt-d;libboost_atomic-mt-d;libboost_atomic-mt;libboost_atomic;libboost_atomic-mgw8-mt-s-d-1_74;libboost_atomic-mgw8-mt-s-d;libboost_atomic-mgw8-mt-s-d;libboost_atomic-mt-s-d-1_74;libboost_atomic-mt-s-d;libboost_atomic-mt-s-d
[cmake] -- Could NOT find Boost (missing: log) (found suitable version "1.74.0", minimum required is "1.74.0")
[cmake] 
[cmake]     Python3_INCLUDE_DIRS=C:/Program Files/WindowsApps/PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.1520.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0/include
[cmake]     Python3_LIBRARIES=C:/Program Files/WindowsApps/PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.1520.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0/libs/python38.lib
[cmake] 
[cmake] -- Configuring done
[cmake] -- Generating done
[cmake] -- Build files have been written to: F:/proj/build
[cmakefileapi-parser] Неожиданная версия модели кода cmake-file-api (2.1). Ожидаемая версия: (2.0). Возможно, конфигурация IntelliSense задана неправильно.
[cmakefileapi-parser] Неожиданная версия модели кода cmake-file-api (2.1). Ожидаемая версия: (2.0). Возможно, конфигурация IntelliSense задана неправильно.
```

В папке с boost все нужные файлы для его работы — имеются.
Сам CMakeLists.txt выглядит примерно так:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.18.1)
project(proj)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)

set(SOURCE_FILE src/main.cpp)

#BOOST

ADD_DEFINITIONS(-DBoost_NO_BOOST_CMAKE=ON)

set(Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS        ON)  # only find static libs
set(Boost_DEBUG ON)
set(Boost_VERBOSE ON)
set(Boost_USE_DEBUG_LIBS         ON) # ignore debug libs and

find_package(Boost 1.74.0 COMPONENTS log REQUIRED)
include_directories(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS})

if(Boost_FOUND)
    MESSAGE( STATUS "Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS = ${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS}.")
    MESSAGE( STATUS "Boost_LIBRARIES = ${BOOST_LIBRARYDIR}.")
    MESSAGE( STATUS "Boost_LIB_VERSION = ${Boost_LIB_VERSION}.")
endif()
    



add_executable(proj ${SOURCE_FILE})

add_subdirectory(lib/googletest)
add_subdirectory(test)

if(WIN32)
    target_link_libraries(proj ws2_32)
    target_link_libraries(proj wsock32) 
endif()

target_compile_definitions(proj PRIVATE RESOURCES_DIR=\"${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}\")
target_link_libraries(proj LINK_PUBLIC ${Boost_LIBRARIES})
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17844085/boost-log-with-cmake-causing-undefined-reference-error

Comment: Сделайте минимальный пример проекта, воспроизводящий ошибку. Попробуйте там динамически линковаться, а не статически (обычно для статической линковки нужны все зависимости). Используйте современные команды, а не `ADD_DEFINITIONS`, у вас же свежая версия CMake. Почитайте доку https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FindBoost.html, линковать надо через IMPORTED таргеты, `include_directories` также не нужен обычно

Answer (score 1):

Как то так

```
add_definitions(-DBOOST_COROUTINES_NO_DEPRECATION_WARNING)
  find_package(Boost COMPONENTS program_options log log_setup program_options context coroutine date_time thread system program_options regex REQUIRED)
  set(Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS        ON) # only find static libs
  set(Boost_USE_MULTITHREADED      ON)
  set(Boost_USE_STATIC_RUNTIME    OFF)
  set(B_LIB ${Boost_LOG_LIBRARY} ${Boost_LOG_SETUP_LIBRARY})
  target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME}_CPP PRIVATE ${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS})
  link_directories(${Boost_LIBRARY_DIRS})
  include_directories(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS})
```

ну а потом

```
 target_link_libraries( ххх B_LIB)
```

Comment: Что-то странное. Зачем два `find_package`, например? И `B_LIB` зачем?

Comment: @dIm0n да 2ой лишний - поправил - мне так проще чтоб потом в таргете не писать 6 буство и тд

Answer (score 1):

Ради интереса сделал обычный бустовский тестовый проект:

```
// main.cpp

#include <boost/log/trivial.hpp>

int main() {
    BOOST_LOG_TRIVIAL(trace) << "A trace severity message";
    BOOST_LOG_TRIVIAL(debug) << "A debug severity message";
    BOOST_LOG_TRIVIAL(info) << "An informational severity message";
    BOOST_LOG_TRIVIAL(warning) << "A warning severity message";
    BOOST_LOG_TRIVIAL(error) << "An error severity message";
    BOOST_LOG_TRIVIAL(fatal) << "A fatal severity message";
}
```

с таким конфигом:

```
# CMakeLists.txt

cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.18)
project(test_boost_log)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)

find_package(Boost REQUIRED COMPONENTS log)

add_executable(test_boost_log main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(test_boost_log PRIVATE Boost::log)
```

Всё работает.

Кстати, в 1 абзаце документации сказано *"If your application consists of more than one module (e.g. an exe and one or several dll's) that use Boost.Log, the library must be built as a shared object. If you have a single executable or a single module that works with Boost.Log, you may build the library as a static library."*, так что это ещё 1 причина возможных проблем.